# Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

I am getting this error message for the below code, however, can not see where the error is referring to. I thought that parenthesis referred to semicolons and commas. I assume there is something I am missing, any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE BRANCH(
BranchID        Int     NOT NULL,
Street          Char(50)    NOT NULL,
City            Char(30)    NOT NULL,
Postcode        Char(10)    NOT NULL,
TelephoneNumber     Int(11)     NOT NULL,
ManagerName     VarChar(40) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT      BRANCH_PK   PRIMARY KEY(BranchID)
 );
```

Comment: Just ran it (sqlite3), works fine for me.

Comment: what dbms are you running this against? if MySQL, then it works - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17761

Comment: fyi, parenthesis means `(` and `)`, not semicolons and commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE BRANCH(
BranchID        Int     NOT NULL,
Street          Char(50)    NOT NULL,
City            Char(30)    NOT NULL,
Postcode        Char(10)    NOT NULL,
TelephoneNumber     Int     NOT NULL,
ManagerName     VarChar(40) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT      BRANCH_PK   PRIMARY KEY(BranchID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, must've been the Int!